# Condition of $\log(x)$ around $x =1$.

Tags: numerical-methods, condition-number

As far as my understanding of condition numbers go, they represent how much an error in input can change output.

What I don't understand is why for values of $\log(x)$ around $x=1$ is the condition number $C(x) = 1/\log(x)$ so large? Shouldn't $C(x)$ be larger as $x \to 0$?

Comment: when $x \to 0$, $1/\log(x) \to 0$

Comment: $\log 1 = 0$ so surely you would *expect* $C(x) = \frac 1{\log x}$ to be very large for $x \to 1$, wouldn't you?  .... likewise $\log 0 = -\infty$ so $C(x) = \frac 1{\log x}$ should be very small at $x \to 0$.

Comment: I realize how the function 1/logx behaves as x - > 1, I just don't realize how the accurately reflects the condition of log(x) around 1. The graph of log(x) seems reasonably well conditioned around x = 1

Answer (score 0):

$\log 1 = 0$.  So $x \to 1$ then $\log x \to 0$.  And $C(x) = \frac 1{\log x} \to \infty$.

$\log 0$ is undefined but $x \to 0^+$ then $\log x\to -\infty$ and so $C(x) = \frac 1{\log x} \to 0^-$.

You seem to be confusing $x$ with $\log x$.  $C(x)= \frac 1 {\log x}$ will be "very large" when $\log x$ is "very close" to $0$.  Which occurs *precisely* when $x \to 1$.  It does *not* occur with $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, $C(x) \to +\infty$ as $\log(x) \to 0^+$. You probably know that $\log(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 1$. More specifically, since we are dealing with $C(x) \to +\infty$, we restrict it to $\log(x) \to 0^+$ as $x \to 1^+$.
$$\lim_{x\to 1^+} \log(x) = 0^+$$
Hence, $$\lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{1}{\log(x)} = +\infty$$
Which explains the large rise in numbers as $x$ tends to $1$ from the RHS.